# /bin/sh: 1: arm-linux-gcc: not found on ubuntu

Tags: linux, gcc, path, cross-compiling

I m trying to build using gcc arm cross compiler and i get following error

Building file: ../src/application.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
arm-linux-gcc -O3 -Wall -c -I -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/application.d" -MT"src/application.d" -o "src/application.o" "../src/application.c"
/bin/sh: 1: arm-linux-gcc: not found

i also check my path setting and i had proper valid path to the arm-linux-gcc
and also linux "which" command gives the correct path of arm-linux-gcc..

could some one let me know what i am doing wrong..?

Comment: can you add the output of PATH & which command and also a long list of binaries of your arm toolchain

Comment: echo $PATH
/opt/****/****/****/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

which arm-linux-gcc
/opt/****/****/*****/usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured it out,very silly mistake. i was trying to run 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system.